# Screen brightness on X220 with Fn keys does not work below some threshold

Tags: debian, xfce, thinkpad, brightness

I have a Thinkpad X220 and am running Debian 9 stable with kernel

`Linux version 4.9.0-8-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc version 6.3.0 20170516 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) ) #1 SMP Debian 4.9.135-1 (2018-11-11)`

using XFCE 4.12, and have encountered a rather strange bug.

Basically, if I initially start from the max brightness setting, and want to reduce it to near 0 (5 seems to be the dimmest setting using the power manager scrollbar), if I use the Fn key, it is unable to go below the value 383 (as reported by `cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`) **unless** I manually use the scrollbar in the power manager. The actual value (383) does seem to actually depend on which brightness value I start with, and I can always reach the max level using the other Fn key, but the minimum level just gets stuck on a very high value, making it annoying to adjust in low-light settings. Is there a way to fix this behaviour so I can properly reduce the brightness below this (seemingly arbitrary) threshold using the Fn key?

**EDIT**: unchecking "Handle display brightness keys" from the `xfce4-power-manager` makes the lowest brightness go down to a hard bound of 73 (as reported by `cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`), which seems to correspond to 0 (as reported by `cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness`), so I'm thinking this has to do with the ACPI. I tried passing `acpi_backlight=vendor thinkpad-acpi.brightness_enable=1` as a kernel boot parameter, but this seems to disable the brightness hotkeys altogether, while passing `acpi.brightness_switch_enabled=0` doesn't fix the issue.